# Add values to specific rows in a new column. Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

```
def main():
    bulletins = os.listdir(INPUT_DATA_DIR)

    df = pd.DataFrame(bulletins)
    df.columns = ['html']
    df['html'] = df.html.apply(read_file)
    df['id'] = df.html.apply(get_document_id)
    df['res_html'] = df.html.apply(get_resolution)
    df['type'] = df.res_html.apply(get_type)
    print(df.head())

  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code creates the following table:

```
                                                html  ...   type
0  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...  ...   Text
1  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...  ...  Table
2  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...  ...  Table
3  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...  ...   Text
4  <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-...  ...  Table
```

the "res_html" column contains html code. The "type" column contains information about whether the code in the previous column contains a table. If it exists, the "type" column contains the value "Table". If there is no table, the value "Text"is entered. I made sure that the "type" column is filled in correctly.

Next, I had to add the "row" column. For cases where the "type" column is equal to" Table", a new value must be entered in the" row " column.

```
def main():
    bulletins = os.listdir(INPUT_DATA_DIR)

    df = pd.DataFrame(bulletins)
    df.columns = ['html']
    df['html'] = df.html.apply(read_file)
    df['id'] = df.html.apply(get_document_id)
    df['res_html'] = df.html.apply(get_resolution)
    df['type'] = df.res_html.apply(get_type)
    print(df.head())

    row_index = df.index[df['type'] == 'Table'].tolist()
    df.loc[row_index, 'row'] = df.res_html.apply(get_type_table)

def get_type_table(tree):
    tbody = tree.find('tbody')
    row = tbody.find('tr')

    if row:
        return 'tr'
    return ''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

At this stage I have a problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roman/etlsrc/parsers/hp_ux/app/resolution_field.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/roman/etlsrc/parsers/hp_ux/app/resolution_field.py", line 25, in main
    df.loc[row_index, 'row'] = df.res_html.apply(get_type_table)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 3848, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2329, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "/home/roman/etlsrc/parsers/hp_ux/app/resolution_field.py", line 63, in get_type_table
    row = tbody.find('tr')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

This is because the "`get_type_table`" function is applied to all rows in my DataFrame

What do I need to do to make this function apply only to rows that contain the value "Table" in the "Type"column?

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped me completely! but to be honest, I didn't understand your answer. What is the difference between my implementation and yours?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you call `get_type_table` you are skipping the `tree` argument, AND it probably should be:

```
df.loc[row_index, 'row'] = df.loc[row_index, :].res_html.apply(get_type_table(tree))
```

The `.loc[row_index, :]` after the `=` is what you were missing so it wouldn't call `get_type_table` on all rows.